# Booting to applications on SD Windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I've developed a simple application that run on WM6 (Motorola MC45 Mobile Computer) that is stored on a SD. I need that program to run on started up when booting from the SD. Is there any way to do that so its the first thing the user see without moving it to the unit or little to not changes on the device?
i.e when booting from the SD it runs my hello world application not affecting any other processes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to autorun an application is to name it AutoRun.exe and place it inside a 2577 folder on the SD Card. Per definition this special location and name is reserved to autorun apps from external volumes.

Some OEMs extend this and chain start several 2577 autorun.exe from there persistent storage and the SD Card. Or they only start from persistent storage or SD Card.

The name 2577 is derived from the processor architecture and is different on per-windows mobile 6.x systems.

MortScript can be used with AutoRun.exe if you need more script like options.

Further on there are several Kiosk Mode application helpers like AppCenter or Intermec Launcher or what the OEMs offer for there devices.